# Mobile Report Publisher. "Time chart" and "Number with delta" gauge

Tags: ssrs-2016, sql-server-mobile

I have some questions about SSRS 2016 Mobile Report Publisher.

1. Is there any possibility to change the appearance of lines (style, color, thickness) in Time chart gauge? It seems that there is no standard way to do that.
   Screenshot - Time chart line appearance:
   [image: Screenshot - Time chart line appearance]
2. Number with delta gauge. Ranges of zones (maximum, neutral, minimum) could be set via “Set ranges…” button. Could these values be set not manually, but be taken from DB and set programmatically?
   Screenshot - Ranges in Number with delta gauge:
   [image: Screenshot - Ranges in Number with delta gauge]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not increase or decrease the line color, thickness or style as per your choice but you have some color palette choice from there you can set as per the look and feel best suited to you. You can find it on top right corner of **Mobile Report Publisher** Tool.
   [image: Color Palette]
2. You can change it manually as per your need but through program till now i haven't seen any option.